# data append to a php Implode statement producing incorrect results

Tags: php

I have a data table with the contents of train departures, and another data table with calling stations.
Both tables have the same unique ServiceID.

The first table returns all the data and the second table returns data relating to each ServiceID.

First table:

```
$query_fids = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM UKRail_departboards WHERE Origin_crs ='".$sta."' ORDER BY ScheduleTime ASC";
$query_limit_fids = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_fids, $startRow_fids, $maxRows_fids);
$fids = mysqli_query($con,$query_limit_fids);
$row_fids = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fids);
$totalRows_fids = mysqli_num_rows($fids);
```

When the script runs it produces rows of train departures on one line and the list of stations which the train calls at.
The issue I have is, the first record is displayed with the correct data, for example:

```
11:36 Thameslink Bedford 1 On time
Calling at:East Croydon, London Bridge, London Blackfriars, City Thameslink, Farringdon, London St Pancras (Intl), West Hampstead Thameslink, St Albans, Harpenden, Luton Airport Parkway, Luton, Leagrave, Harlington, Flitwick, Bedford
```

The second row of data displays the correct first line of data correctly but the second line displays the second line of data from the first row and the line of data relating to the second row. So I end up with the following:

```
11:36 Thameslink Brighton 7 On time
Calling at:East Croydon, London Bridge, London Blackfriars, City Thameslink, Farringdon, London St Pancras (Intl), West Hampstead Thameslink, St Albans, Harpenden, Luton Airport Parkway, Luton, Leagrave, Harlington, Flitwick, Bedford, Three Bridges, Haywards Heath, Wivelsfield, Burgess Hill, Hassocks, Preston Park, Brighton
```

The second line from the first record is line 1 and the second line from row 2 looking like this:

```
//First row, second line of data.
East Croydon, London Bridge, London Blackfriars, City Thameslink, Farringdon, London St Pancras (Intl), West Hampstead Thameslink, St Albans, Harpenden, Luton Airport Parkway, Luton, Leagrave, Harlington, Flitwick, Bedford

// Secord row, second line of data.
East Croydon, London Bridge, London Blackfriars, City Thameslink, Farringdon, London St Pancras (Intl), West Hampstead Thameslink, St Albans, Harpenden, Luton Airport Parkway, Luton, Leagrave, Harlington, Flitwick, Bedford, Three Bridges, Haywards Heath, Wivelsfield, Burgess Hill, Hassocks, Preston Park, Brighton
```

The second rows line of data should be:

```
Three Bridges, Haywards Heath, Wivelsfield, Burgess Hill, Hassocks, Preston Park, Brighton
```

This is the code that produces the second line of data from each record.

```
<section id="section">
<?php
  do {    ?>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="fixed1"><?php print date("H:i",strtotime($row_fids['ScheduleTime']));?></div>
    <div class="fixed2"><?php print $row_fids['Operator'];?></div>
    <div class="fixed3"><?php print $row_fids['Dest_location'];?></div>
    <div class="fixed4"><?php echo $row_fids['Platform'];?></div>
    <div class="fixed5"><?php print $row_fids['Estimated'];?></div>
   <?php
// This query using the result of the first query's ServiceID to look up data from the second query, below.
   $query_calls = "SELECT DISTINCT callingPoint FROM UKRail_departboard_calling_points WHERE ServiceID = '".$row_fids['ServiceID']."'";
   $calls = mysqli_query($navex, $query_calls) or die(mysqli_error($navex));
   $row_calls = mysqli_fetch_assoc($calls);
   $totalRows_calls = mysqli_num_rows($calls);

   do {
     $names[] = $row_calls['callingPoint']; // This creates an array of calling stations
     $callingat = implode(', ', $names); // uses "implode" to create a string of stations
   }while($row_calls = mysqli_fetch_array($calls));?>
    //Display calling stations
   <div class="callingatheader">Calling at: </div>
   <div class="callslist"><?php echo $callingat;?></div>
<?php    } while($row_fids = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fids));?>
</section>
```

My question is, why is the second row of data appending the data of the first row from the second line of the first row.
This continues as more records are displayed, for example:

```
11:39 Southern Portsmouth & Southsea Bognor Regis 7 On time
East Croydon, London Bridge, London Blackfriars, City Thameslink, Farringdon, London St Pancras (Intl), West Hampstead Thameslink, St Albans, Harpenden, Luton Airport Parkway, Luton, Leagrave, Harlington, Flitwick, Bedford, Three Bridges, Haywards Heath, Wivelsfield, Burgess Hill, Hassocks, Preston Park, Brighton, Three Bridges, Crawley, Horsham, Barnham, Chichester, Havant, Fratton, Portsmouth & Southsea, Billingshurst, Pulborough, Arundel, Ford, Bognor Regis
```

The above row of data displays the second line of data for the previous records.
if I were to echo out $row_calls['callingPoint'] the data is correct but when I use implode it's not.
Can anyone see why and where I have gone wrong?

Comment: This part plus the next line seem suspect: `$names[] = $row_calls['callingPoint']`. The comment says that it creates an array, which is partly true, but in reality it also appends to the array if it already exists. Then the next line immediately implodes it, but that seems weird to be done inside of the loop.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks for the look. reading what you siad I have just solved the issue. Just before } while($row_fids = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fids));?> I now have unset ($names); } while($row_fids = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fids));. works.

Comment: @DCJones, can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Hi I think I have posted it as the answer.

Comment: I'm only seeing the comment above, not an answer below

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @ChrisHaas. Reading what you said, I have just solved the issue.

Just before `} while($row_fids = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fids));?>` I now have `unset ($names); } while($row_fids = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fids));` works.